# How to get information from a client, then automatically use that in a form?

Tags: php, html, cookies, automation

I'm trying to get a clients information on their computer and automatically using that to determine some components of the form. This form is ranging from the users name-location and I'm trying to make it so that the setup process is quick and easy. I'm also wondering if I can take information from cookies on previously saved websites? Here is the visible part of the html form I have so far.

```
     <td><input type="text" class="username" id="username" name="username" maxlength="45" size="30" value = "" /></td>
<td>E-Mail</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="email" size="30" value="" maxlength="100"/></td>


     <td>Password (between 6 and 16 chars):</td>
     <td valign="top"><input class="password" id="password" type="password" name="password"
         size="16" maxlength="16"/></td>

     <td>Confirm password</td>
     <td><input type="password" name="passwd2" size="16" maxlength="16"/></td>

   <tr>
     <td>Time Zone: </td>
     <td><select id="tzone" name="tzone" >
        <option value="Pacific/Midway" >(GMT-11:00) Midway Island, Samoa</option>
<option value="Pacific/Honolulu" >(GMT-10:00) Hawaii</option>
<option value="America/Anchorage" >(GMT-09:00) Alaska</option>

etc...
  </select>
    </td>
```

All I need is PHP to automate some parts of this form, such as the timezone, and make is easier for the user (I already know how to get the persons timezone, it's just I'm not able to use that in the `<option select>`.

Comment: you can only get the cookie for the current website you are on. there are probably ways to get other cookies but that would be malicous activity

Comment: and might get caught by the anti-spyware etc.

Comment: you can use the /www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp for getting the location

Comment: if you want to make sign up faster, you can use facebook login api as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you.

HTML with GET form or POST

```
<select id="tzone" name="tzone" >
<option value="-:11" >(GMT-11:00) Midway Island, Samoa</option>
<option value="-:10" >(GMT-10:00) Hawaii</option>
<option value="-:09" >(GMT-09:00) Alaska</option>
<option value="+:04" >(GMT+04:00) Russia</option>
</select>
```

PHP

```
$selected_zone = $_GET["tzone"];// for POST use $_POST["tzone"]
$zone = explode(":", $selected_zone);
$timestamp = date("H:i:s");
if($zone[0] == "-" ){
    $time = date( "H:i:s", strtotime( $timestamp ) - $zone[1] * 3600 );
}else{
    $time = date( "H:i:s", strtotime( $timestamp ) + $zone[1] * 3600 );
}
```

And will out put time like this

15:00:00